# How to return several arrays of doubles as a table in C# SQLCLR function

Tags: sql-server, c#, sql-clr, set-returning-functions

What I have is a CLR `SqlFunction` that produces 3 arrays of doubles. I would like this function to return something appropriate so that the `FillRowMethod` can output it for me as a table in T-SQL. It works fine for 1 array but I'm having trouble extending it to several. I'm mostly unsure on what to return from my method. Some code below:

```csharp
[SqlFunction(DataAccess = DataAccessKind.Read, FillRowMethodName = "FillRow",
    TableDefinition = "impliedVol float, maturity float, strike float")]
public static IEnumerable getStrippedCapletVolatilitiesFromCapVolatilityCurve(
     string uploadDate, double strike, double yearsForward, double intervalDuration,
     string curve, string surface)
    
//Create 3 arrays of doubles
    double[] array1;
    double[] array2;
    double[] array3;

    return [???];
}
    

public static void FillRow(object obj,
     out SqlDouble impliedVol, out SqlDouble maturity, out SqlDouble strike)
{
   //impliedVol = (double)obj;  //This is what I do if only returning one array
}
```

EDIT:

Based on feedback this is my new attempted solution.

```
public static IEnumerable getStrippedCapletVolatilitiesFromCapVolatilityCurve(string uploadDate, double strike, double yearsForward, double intervalDuration, string curve, string surface)
    {
            //omitted code above this line.
        CapletStipping thisCapletStripping = new CapletStipping(maturities, forwardRates, discountingRates, intervalDuration);
        double[][] theseStrippedCapletVols = thisCapletStripping.getCapletCurveForGivenStrike(flatVols, strike);

         List<capletVolatilityNode> capletVolatilitiesList = new List<capletVolatilityNode>(theseStrippedCapletVols[0].Length);

        for (int i = 0; i < theseStrippedCapletVols[0].Length; i += 1)
        {
            capletVolatilityNode thisCapletVolatilityNode = new capletVolatilityNode(theseStrippedCapletVols[0][i], theseStrippedCapletVols[1][i], theseStrippedCapletVols[2][i]);
            capletVolatilitiesList[i] = thisCapletVolatilityNode;
        }

        return capletVolatilitiesList; // theseStrippedCapletVols;
    }

    public class capletVolatilityNode
    {
        public double impliedVol;
        public double maturity;
        public double strike;
        public capletVolatilityNode(double impliedVol_, double maturity_, double strike_)
        {
            impliedVol = impliedVol_; 
            maturity = maturity_; 
            strike = strike_;
        }
    }

public static void FillRow(Object obj, out SqlDouble impliedVol, out SqlDouble maturity, out SqlDouble strike)
{

    capletVolatilityNode row = (capletVolatilityNode)obj;

    impliedVol = Convert.ToDouble(row.impliedVol);
    maturity = Convert.ToDouble(row.maturity);
    strike = Convert.ToDouble(row.strike);

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are wanting to return the 3 arrays as 3 separate result sets, that is not possible for a function, whether SQLCLR or T-SQL. You would need to create a stored procedure instead in order to return multiple result sets.

If the 3 arrays represent 3 columns of a single result set such that they will all have the same number of items *and* the index value of one is conceptually associated with the same index value of the others (i.e. `array1[x]` is associated with `array2[x]` and `array3[x]`, while `array1[y]` is associated with `array2[y]` and `array3[y]`, and so on), then a simple array is the wrong type of collection. You can only return a single collection where each item/element in the collection represents a row in the result set (or at least enough info to construct the desired row). That singular collection, when returned from the `SqlFunction` method, is iterated over, calling the `FillRowMethod` for each item/element. One item/element is passed into the `FillRowMethod` which constructs the final result set structure and values and passes them back (hence you have the opportunity to create and/or translate values from the original item before passing them back).

In this latter case, you would need to create a class similar to:

```csharp
private class volatility
{
    public double impliedVol;
    public double maturity;
    public double strike;
}
```

Then, create a generic list of those in your `getStrippedCapletVolatilitiesFromCapVolatilityCurve` method, add a new item to that collection for every row to return, and then return that list/collection. Your `FillRowMethod` will be called with the first parameter (as `object`) being of type `volatility`. That is where you will populate the `out` params from those properties of `volatility`. For example:

```csharp
private static void FillRow(object obj,
     out SqlDouble impliedVol, out SqlDouble maturity, out SqlDouble strike)
{
    volatility row = (volatility)obj;

    impliedVol = new SqlDouble(row.impliedVol);
    maturity = new SqlDouble(row.maturity);
    strike = new SqlDouble(row.strike);
}
```

Now, it might be possible to handle this as a two-dimensional array (i.e. `double[][]`) that you return from the main `SqlFunction`, but then the `FillRow` method would be sent a `double[]` since the first dimension is broken out into individual calls to the `FillRow` method. I've never tried this specific approach, but it should work as follows:

```csharp
private static void FillRow(object obj,
     out SqlDouble impliedVol, out SqlDouble maturity, out SqlDouble strike)
{
    double[] row = (double[])obj;

    impliedVol = new SqlDouble(row[0]);
    maturity = new SqlDouble(row[1]);
    strike = new SqlDouble(row[2]);
}
```

**ALSO:**

It just occurred to me that you could even forgo the generic list / collection and stream the contents of the `double[][]` array out to the result set, one item / row at a time. Go ahead and try this:

```csharp
public static IEnumerable getStrippedCapletVolatilitiesFromCapVolatilityCurve(...)
{
    //omitted code above this line.
    CapletStipping thisCapletStripping =
       new CapletStipping(maturities, forwardRates, discountingRates, intervalDuration);
    double[][] theseStrippedCapletVols =
       thisCapletStripping.getCapletCurveForGivenStrike(flatVols, strike);

    // THIS PART IS DIFFERENT -- begin
    capletVolatilityNode thisCapletVolatilityNode = new capletVolatilityNode();

    for (int i = 0; i < theseStrippedCapletVols[0].Length; i += 1)
    {
        thisCapletVolatilityNode.impliedVol = theseStrippedCapletVols[0][i];
        thisCapletVolatilityNode.maturity = theseStrippedCapletVols[1][i];
        thisCapletVolatilityNode.strike = theseStrippedCapletVols[2][i];

        yield return thisCapletVolatilityNode; // return rows individually
    }

    return; // cannot return anything when using "yield return"
    // THIS PART IS DIFFERENT -- end
}

private class capletVolatilityNode
{
    public double impliedVol;
    public double maturity;
    public double strike;
}
```

There are some restrictions when using `yield return`, but if your process allows for this construct, then this will not only be faster, but also take up less memory. These benefits are due to this code skipping the step of copying the results of the `getCapletCurveForGivenStrike()` method to a separate collection (i.e the Generic List) just to return it to T-SQL (in which case you need to wait while it copies the collection and consumes more memory).

---

On a related note: use the `Sql*` types for the input parameters instead of standard .NET types. Meaning, use `SqlString` instead of `string` and `SqlDouble` instead of `double`. You can then easily get the .NET native type from those via the `Value` property that all of the `Sql*` types have (e.g. `SqlString.Value` passes back a `string`, etc).

For more info on working with SQLCLR in general, please visit: [SQLCLR Info](https://sqlclr.org/)

Comment: Hi, no not quite I just want to return them as 1 result set. I have rewritten the code a bit so that I instead have my results (that I want in an SQL table) as a 2 dimensional array of doubles, double[][] outPutArray that is returned by my "Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlFunction" function.

I still have trouble building my FillRow function however to make it fill the rows of my table with the data in my two dimensional array.

Comment: @Oscar I have updated my answer. Please review.

Comment: Hi, I updated my post with my new code based on your feedback. It is giving me some index out of bounds error that I'm still trying to figure out, but is this along the lines of what you meant?

Comment: Yes, your code looks correct.

Comment: Hi, thank you @DavidBrowne-Microsoft. I had to change the logic to use capletVolatilitiesList.add(...) instead of capletVolatilitiesList[i] = ... to make it work, but now it works.

Comment: @Oscar Thanks for accepting. Did you see my update on how to possibly use the 2-dimension array by itself without the separate class, generic list, and loop to convert the array into the list? If it works it would cut down on duplicating the data in memory and wasting cycles copying the data over. Also, don't use `Convert.ToDouble` as the value is already a `double`. Please use `new SqlDouble` as shown in my example code. Also, please change the input parameters as I have noted (e.g. `string` -> `SqlString`). And, is it `CapletStipping` or `CapletStripping`? The "r" is added in most places.

Comment: @SolomonRutzky Ah yes I see it now. Something like that is what I first attempted (but I didn't think about the fact that the first dimension is broken out, so I tried to to do double[][] row = (double[][])obj; and went crazy not understanding why it gave me an error. I do think it should work probably if you do it your way, to me it makes a lot of sense. I will give it a try on monday.


And thank you for the suggestions on sqldouble etc. I will make sure to fix that.


It's supposed to be capletstRipping, I must have made a typo in the function name that has gone unnoticed.

Comment: @SolomonRutzky The original way you showed me, with a helper class (volatility), is the standard approach though? Is that right? Your way has the benefit of being able to output a combination of double, strings, ints etc. and not be confined to a single data type so I think I like that a lot better for generality

Comment: @Oscar In general, yes, using a class (or sometimes even a struct) to return the rows is how it's done. However, it occurred to me that there is another option, one that is possibly quite a bit better. It might be possible to stream the results out in which case you still get to skip duplicating the data in memory _and_ it allows for multiple datatypes. Please review the **ALSO** section that I added to this answer.

Comment: @SolomonRutzky yes I saw, very interesting. I will let you know on Monday if it works as expected

Comment: @SolomonRutzky I tried your way of streaming data using "yield return" but it is giving me some error: "Data access is not allowed in this context. Either the context is a function or method not marked with DataAccessKind.Read or SystemDataAccessKind.Read, is a callback to obtain data from FillRow method of a Table Valued Function, or is a UDT validation method."

This seems to be related to the Yield return statement.

Comment: @Oscar The example code at the very top of your question shows the method decorated with `DataAccess = DataAccessKind.Read`. Do you still have that? If not, then try putting that back in. If yes, then does the `getCapletCurveForGivenStrike` method do data access / query the DB?

Comment: @SolomonRutzky Yes it's still there. And no, all the DB querying is done in the getStrippedCapletVolatilitiesFromCapVolatilityCurve function

Comment: @Oscar That must be the "omitted code" section at the top of that method. I did some testing and found the problem: you're using `context connection = true;`, which is usually preferred but doesn't allow doing `yield return;`. So, you can either a) stick with the original code using the in-process connection and _not_ stream the results back, or b) switch to using a standard / external connection which connects as a separate session (more memory + CPU used plus no access to current transaction / temp objects and can't be a `SAFE` assembly) but _can_ stream results back.